# map from array to integer not working properly in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary

I have a code which uses maps from arrays to integers, but it doesn't work properly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    map <int*, int> abcd;
    int a[2], b[2];
    a[0]= 2;
    a[1]= 3;
    abcd[a]=1;
    b[0]= 2;
    b[1]= 3;
    cout<<abcd[b];
    return 0;
}
```

Note that arrays a and b here are equal, so abcd[b] should be equal to 1. But the output is 0. Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for the poor English.

Comment: You never set `abcd[b]`.

Comment: `a` and `b` may be equal, but `&a[0]` and `&b[0]`, which you're using as keys, are not. Arrays are not pointers. Pointers are not arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Your map is storing `int*` keys, not arrays.  If you want to store arrays, try `std::array<int,2>` if there's always 2 elements, or `std::vector<int>` if it varies....

Because you're storing pointers, `abcd[a]=1` is actually saying "if I index again using the address of `a[]`, find the value `1`.  `abcd[b]` looks for a different key `&b` which will never be equal to `&a` given they're distinct variables at different addresses.  The pointer keys have nothing to do with the array content; another consequence of that is that if you change the values in `a[]` and look for `abcd[a]` you'll still find `1`....

Answer (score 0):

`map <int*, int>` uses comparator that compares pointers not the values, even though the contents of `a` and `b` are same they point to different memory location hence are different keys for the map.

The default value of a unique key is 0 (value-initialized `int` ) in this case, therefore  `abcd[b]` shows `0`